# Symfony 2.3 : right way to access the form underlying object?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.3

I wonder what the right way to access the form underlying object in symfony 2.3 ?
Should I use this :

```
$underlyingObject = $builder->getData();
echo get_class($underlyingObject) ; // prints App\MyBundle\Entity\Foobar
```

or that :

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,function (FormEvent $formEvent) {
    $underlyingObject = $formEvent->getData() ;
    echo get_class($underlyingObject) ; // prints App\MyBundle\Entity\Foobar too !
});
```

Here the setDefaultOptions method, that defines the class of the mapped object :

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => ' App\MyBundle\Entity\Foobar',
    ));

}
```

Any suggestions ? 
Greetings, Ben

Comment: I guess the question is for what purpose you want to access the underlying  object?

Comment: I'd recommend using the `getNormData()` cause depending on when you invoke `getData()` it may return an array also.